# Eclipse remote system fail to create folder

Tags: eclipse, remote-access

I am trying to use eclipse remote to edit my files on server. But sometimes I was denied to create file or folder in certain directory since I do not have enough authority.
Anyone know how could I do it in eclipse instead of log-in to server and use sudo command?